# About URI relativize

Tags: java, uri

Please see the following java code:

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.site1.com/aaa/");
URL u2 = new URL("http://www.site1.com/aaa/ccc/aaa/");
URI r = u2.toURI().relativize(u.toURI());
System.out.println(r); // print:   http://www.site1.com/aaa/
```

However, how to return the REALLY relative path: ../../ ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Gurwinder, because r is relative path, I expected the r is ../../  , since   URI r = u.toURI().relativize(u2.toURI());   please NOTE: u.relative(u2), it can get correct result, however, if u2.relative(u),   can not get relative path.

Answer (score 2):

the code, hope it's useful :)

```
/**
 * split path
 * the String.split() is a little ambiguous because it might return empty string in the returned array that is unexpected.
 * in this function, the only case that returned array is empty is when path is /
 * @param path
 * @return
 */
public static String[] splitPath(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(path);
    int s0 = 0;
    int s1,e1;
    while(m.find()) {
        s1 = m.start();
        e1 = m.end();
        if(s1-s0>0) {
            ret.add(path.substring(s0,s1));
        }
        s0 = e1;
    }
    if(s0<path.length()) {
        ret.add(path.substring(s0));
    }
    String[] a = ret.toArray(new String[0]);
    return a;
}

/**
 * get the relative path against the base dir.
 * @param base - the base path, must be a directory.
 * @param path - the path to visit, can be directory or file.
 * @return - the relative path from base to the path.
 */
public static String relativize(String baseDir, String path) {
    if(!baseDir.endsWith("/")) {
        baseDir = baseDir + "/"; // assume the baseDir is always a directory.
    }
    String[] bases = splitPath(baseDir);
    String[] paths = splitPath(path);
    int p = 0, q = 0;

    while(p<bases.length && q<paths.length && bases[p].equals(paths[q])) {
        p++;
        q++;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
    int i;
    for(i=bases.length-1;i>=p;i--) {
        sb.append("../");
    }

    for(i=q;i<paths.length;i++) {
        sb.append(paths[i]);
        if(i!=paths.length-1) {
            sb.append("/");
        }
    }

    if(path.endsWith("/")) {
        // ensure the last char of sb is not /
        i = sb.length();
        if(i>0 && sb.charAt(i-1)!='/') {
            sb.append("/");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

static void testRelativize() {
    String r;
    r = relativize("/", "/acdde");
    if(!"acdde".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("1");
    }

    r = relativize("/a", "/b/c");
    if(!"../b/c".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("2");
    }

    r = relativize("/c", "/c/a/");
    if(!"a/".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("3");
    }

    r = relativize("/c/d", "/c/a/a.txt");
    if(!"../a/a.txt".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("4");
    }

    r = relativize("/c/b/d/", "/c/");
    if(!"../../".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("5");
    }

    r = relativize("/c/d", "/c/d/a.txt");
    if(!"a.txt".equals(r)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("6");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to switch `u2` with `u`, since `u` is the *prefix* of `u2`, like this:

```
URI r = u.toURI().relativize(u2.toURI());
System.out.println(r); // print:   ccc/aaa/
```

According to [URI.relativize() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize(java.net.URI)):

> The relativization of the given URI against this URI is computed as
>   follows:
>
> 1. If either this URI or the given URI are opaque, or if the scheme and authority components of the two URIs are not identical, or **if the
>      path of *this* URI is not a prefix of the path of the *given* URI**, then
>      the **given URI is returned**.
> 2. Otherwise a new relative hierarchical URI is constructed with query and fragment components taken from the given URI and with a path
>      component computed by removing this URI's path from the beginning of
>      the given URI's path.

Comment: Thanks. currently, I writting a tool to rewrite the url in html. I want the url to be relative(to avoid directory changing problem of absolute path) . I know that u.relativize(u2) can get the correct relative path, however, still possible to encounter the situation like u2.relativize(u). seems must write some customized code to implement this... I will post  here some later...

Comment: @chenzero I guess you could easily check that with `u2.startsWith(u)` (and vice versa)

Comment: u2.startsWith(u) is one step of the whole function, because I need to get the relative path, no matther u2 is under u or u2 is up u.